# Finding word context with regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a function to search for the contexts of a given word(w) in a text, with left and right as parameters for flexibility in the number of words to record.

```
import re
def get_context (text, w, left, right):
    text.insert (0, "*START*")
    text.append ("*END*")

    all_contexts = []

    for i in range(len(text)):

        if re.match(w,text[i], 0):

            if i < left:
                context_left = text[:i]

            else:
                context_left = text[i-left:i]

            if len(text) < (i+right):
                context_right = text[i:]

            else: 
                context_right = text[i:(i+right+1)]

            context = context_left + context_right

            all_contexts.append(context)
    return all_contexts
```

So for example if a have a text in the form of a list like this:

> text = ['Python', 'is', 'dynamically', 'typed', 'language', 'Python',
>   'functions', 'really', 'care', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'pass', 'to',
>   'them', 'but', 'you', 'got', 'it', 'the', 'wrong', 'way', 'if', 'you',
>   'want', 'to', 'pass', 'one', 'thousand', 'arguments', 'to', 'your',
>   'function', 'then', 'you', 'can', 'explicitly', 'define', 'every',
>   'parameter', 'in', 'your', 'function', 'definition', 'and', 'your',
>   'function', 'will', 'be', 'automagically', 'able', 'to', 'handle',
>   'all', 'the', 'arguments', 'you', 'pass', 'to', 'them', 'for', 'you']

The function works fine for example:

```
get_context(text, "function",2,2)
[['language', 'python', 'functions', 'really', 'care'], ['to', 'your', 'function', 'then', 'you'], ['in', 'your', 'function', 'definition', 'and'], ['and', 'your', 'function', 'will', 'be']]
```

Now I am trying to build a dictionary with the contexts of every word in the text doing the following:

```
d = {}
for w in set(text):
    d[w] = get_context(text,w,2,2)
```

But I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 2, in <module>
    d[w] = get_context(text,w,2,2)
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 9, in get_context
    if re.match(w,text[i], 0):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 160, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 294, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/sre_compile.py", line 568, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/sre_parse.py", line 760, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/sre_parse.py", line 370, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/sre_parse.py", line 579, in _parse
    raise error("nothing to repeat")
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

I don't understand this error. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "*START*" and "*END*" are being interpreted as regex. Also, note that inserting "*START*" and "*END*" in `text` in the begging of the function will cause problem. You should do it just once.

Here is a complete version of the working code:

```
import re

def get_context(text, w, left, right):
    all_contexts = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if re.match(w,text[i], 0):
            if i < left:
                context_left = text[:i]
            else:
                context_left = text[i-left:i]
            if len(text) < (i+right):
                context_right = text[i:]
            else:
                context_right = text[i:(i+right+1)]
            context = context_left + context_right
            all_contexts.append(context)
    return all_contexts

text = ['Python', 'is', 'dynamically', 'typed', 'language',
        'Python', 'functions', 'really', 'care', 'about', 'what',
        'you', 'pass', 'to', 'them', 'but', 'you', 'got', 'it', 'the',
        'wrong', 'way', 'if', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'pass', 'one',
        'thousand', 'arguments', 'to', 'your', 'function', 'then',
        'you', 'can', 'explicitly', 'define', 'every', 'parameter',
        'in', 'your', 'function', 'definition', 'and', 'your',
        'function', 'will', 'be', 'automagically', 'able', 'to', 'handle',
        'all', 'the', 'arguments', 'you', 'pass', 'to', 'them', 'for', 'you']

text.insert(0, "START")
text.append("END")

d = {}
for w in set(text):
    d[w] = get_context(text,w,2,2)
```

Maybe you can replace `re.match(w,text[i], 0)` with `w == text[i]`.

Comment: Ok, so that was the problem. I didn't thought of those two *START* and *END*. I thought of w==text[i] but I wanted to know why this didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The *whole* thing can be re-written very succinctly follows,

```
text = 'Python is dynamically typed language Python functions really care about what you pass to them but you got it the wrong way if you want to pass one thousand arguments to your function then you can explicitly define every parameter in your function definition and your function will be automagically able to handle all the arguments you pass to them for you'
```

Keeping it a `str`, assuming `context = 'function',`

```
pat = re.compile(r'(\w+\s\w+\s)functions?(?=(\s\w+\s\w+))')
pat.findall(text)
[('language Python ', ' really care'),
 ('to your ', ' then you'),
 ('in your ', ' definition and'),
 ('and your ', ' will be')]
```

Now, minor customization will be needed in the regex to allow for, words like say, `functional` or `functioning` not only `function` or `functions`. But the important idea is to **do away with indexing and go more functional.**

Please comment if this doesn't work out for you, when you apply it in bulk.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to deal with a list if I wanted to change the left and right number of words. I thought of using regular expressions but I couldn't think of a way of setting the number of words on the sides. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Wunter If you are using `list`, always know that `inset` and `+` are red flags. They are veeery slow. `append` is ok.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I am starting to learn programming. I will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the elements in `text` contains characters that are special in a regular expression. If you're just trying to find whether the word is in the string, just use `str.startswith`, i.e.

```
if text[i].startswith(w):  # instead of re.match(w,text[i], 0):
```

But I don't understand why you are checking for that anyways, and not for equality.

Comment: I thought using `re.match` would add some flexibility, for example looking for function and functions at the same time matching `functions?`. Thanks for your suggestion anyways